# Read JSON, return the new (or deleted) object

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, watch

So far, I've been successfully using Ruby to read and write JSON using the `json` gem, and now I want to level up the powers of my tools.

The JSON is served on a read-only server, and is returned as:

```
[{
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "12",
    "username": "Miranda",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "12_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "12_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "12_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}, {
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "13",
    "username": "Elin",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "13_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "13_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "13_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}, {
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "14",
    "username": "Joe",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "14_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "14_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "14_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}
]
```

Now, how can I process just the new object(s) if the next pull from the server has new objects?

example:

```
[
{
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "15",
    "username": "Ellie",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "15_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "15_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "15_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}, {
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "12",
    "username": "Miranda",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "12_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "12_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "12_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}, {
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "13",
    "username": "Elin",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "13_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "13_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "13_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}, {
    "class_name": "User",
    "id": "14",
    "username": "Joe",
    "profile_image_urls": [{
        "url": "14_128x128.jpg",
        "width": 128,
        "height": 128
    }, {
        "url": "14_200x200.jpg",
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200
    }, {
        "url": "14_400x400.jpg",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 400
    }
    ]
}
]
```

*This should return the entire object for id 15*

The solution that fits could:

- use Ruby OR dependency-free javascript
- Save the JSON to a file, and watch/read for changes locally
- Read the JSON from the server directly and juggle the JSON in memory (the script my not be running all the time. The solution needs to be aware so it doesn't miss changes)

Comment: can't save to file from browser, can use localStorage though. Overall question is too broad. You need to break this down into smaller pieces with more specific questions/problems

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is a key which necessarily uniquely identifies each of these objects…

It suffices to just remember the set of IDs you've so far handled, and filter the input such that you exclude those.

```
// this is the set of IDs you've so far handled.
// yes we're just using a regular JS object, since we can agree to use it moreorless like a HashSet.
// you can of course load this in from a file (for example if you saved your progress beforehand)
var handledIDs = {
    "15": true
};

function handleServerOutput(payload) {
    // payload should be in the exact format of your `example` snippet (i.e. a JSON array of objs).
    var objsNeverBeforeHandled = payload.filter(function(obj) {
        // true if that key maps to a true in the `handledIDs` dictionary
        var hasBeenHandled = handledIDs[obj.id];
        // exclude from the filtered payload any object that has been handled
        return !hasBeenHandled;
    });

    // now you can iterate through the `objsNeverBeforeHandled`
    objsNeverBeforeHandled.forEach(function(obj) {
        // do whatever you like with obj
        // …

        // also remember to add it to the set of IDs you've handled
        handledIDs[obj.id] = true;
    });

    // and you have the opportunity to save `handledIDs` somewhere for the next time you need to run this thing.
}
```